# Is react-toolbox ready for webpack 4?

Tags: react-toolbox, webpack-4

I am having a dickens of a time getting the default styles of certain components (namely buttons with icons and dialogs) to display when compiled with Webpack 4 (using the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) in place of the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

Has anyone else found this to be the case when upgrading to Webpack 4?

[annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE5cO.png)